# Is there any way to pass configuration parameters to an Outlook Addin

Tags: javascript, parameters, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a JS Outlook Add-in that I'd like to be able to deploy to multiple sites, but I'd like to deploy the same code to every site and handle configuration data externally, if possible. Something like process.env (that works for a Node.js server App) for a client App. I see it's possible to define Application Settings in Azure, but how can I access the values in the App?

Comment: Can you provide some more clarity here on what you are trying to do? (Just to be sure you are referring to Outlook add-ins such as these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview) 

there is a roaming settings api, but I'm not sure if that would meet your scenario. So if you can describe in more detail what specifically you would like to do, that may help.

Comment: Yes, that link refers to the type of Add-In I'm using. The actual configuration data I want is the ID (web address) of a Node.js server app; currently, I have this hard coded, which is unsatisfactory. Thanks

Comment: Is this hardcoded in the manifest of the Outlook add-in or in the JavaScript for the add-in? And for Azure App Settings, is this what you are referring to? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

Comment: Hard-coded in the App (JS) - AFAIK, the App can't access the Manifest at runtime, otherwise that might be a solution. Re App Settings, yes, that's a relevant link.

Comment: Yes, that's accurate. The add-in's JS cannot access the manifest at runtime. Since the add-in loads the URL specified in the manifest, you can leverage query strings/parameters in the URL and access them at runtime. Will that work? I'm not very familiar with Azure App Settings, so let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: That's a possible work around; will check out and revert ... thanks

Comment: In case this work for you, I've added this option as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're able to distribute a different manifest to each customer, you can add a query parameter to any [SourceLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/sourcelocation) URLs in the manifest to pass information to the add-in on startup.

```
<bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/Taskpane.html?<per-customer query string>" />
```

Comment: after installing addin, how customer can specify the parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Outlook Add-ins Team, that works fine; for the benefit for any other readers, a few details

1. Extracting the parameter value in the target JS is made easy by using URLSearchParams()
2. This solution concentrates the customer variance in the Manifest, leaving the bulk of the solution in JS that is the same for all deployments, a key objective
3. As an aside: the customer variances to the Manifest can be reduced to minimum by using ~remoteAppUrl

Answer (score 1):

I want to extend @JohnD's answer for everyone who wants to have an example:

#### 1. Attach query param to your Taskpane url:

```xml
<bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?param=myParameter"/>
```

#### 2. Get the parameter in JavaScript

```js
let queryString = window.location.search;
// ?param=myParameter
let param = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
// param=myParameter
let myParam = param.get("param");
// myParameter
```

This is an example on how to use it. Hope it helps.