# Outlook Web Add-In - Is it possible to access settings within the Manifest from within a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, xml, outlook-web-addins

I know this is possible when developing a VSTO as you can declare settings in your app.config , and then reference these settings in C# by doing something like Properties.Settings.MadeUpSetting.

But i am wondering is this possible when using a web add in ? My use case is that different people will have different requirements when using this add in, so i presumed the manifest is where i would declare the settings (whose values i can change to suit user A or user B) and then reference them in the JS , but im not sure if this can be done? I am new to this , so any steps in the right direction are much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This is similar to another SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965093/is-there-any-way-to-pass-configuration-parameters-to-an-outlook-addin. A possible way to achieve this scenario would be to add query parameters in the URLs in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to another [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965093/is-there-any-way-to-pass-configuration-parameters-to-an-outlook-addin). A possible way to achieve this scenario would be to add query parameters in the URLs in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up implementing this by saving off any settings to the db, and then retrieving the settings i wanted with an API call and applying these returned settings to my web add in